# Resources for how to design graph/charts well

Tags: charts

One of my projects needs to show users where they rank in certain calculations. I inherited the graph structure from the previous programmer and had to leave it alone while I worked on other parts of the site.

It's time to make the graphs more meaningful, so I'm looking for books/websites/etc about graphs. (Not graph theory!)  Charts that convey comparisons at a glance.

Everyone suggests [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information by Edward Tufte](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961392142) and that's spot on for what I'm looking for, so anything related to that would be great.

Naturally, personal experience about what to do or not would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Stephen Few's book ["Show Me the Numbers"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0970601999) very helpful.